# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible field "post[date]" that is not disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this integration test that is giving me errors that seem to have to do with `fill_in`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'navigate' do
  let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

  let(:post) do
    Post.create(date: Date.today, rationale: "Rationale", user_id: user.id)
  end

  before do
    login_as(@user, :scope => :user)
  end

  describe 'index' do
    before do
      visit posts_path
    end
    it 'can be reached successfully' do
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end

    it 'has a title of Posts' do
      expect(page).to have_content(/Posts/)
    end

    it 'has a list of posts' do
      post1 = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:post)
      post2 = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:second_post)
      visit posts_path
      expect(page).to have_content(/Rationale|content/)
    end

    it 'has a scope so that only post creators can see their posts' do
      other_user = User.create(first_name: 'Non', last_name: 'Authorized', email: 'nonauth@example.com',
                                          password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")

      post_from_other_user = Post.create(date: Date.today, rationale: "This post shouldn't be seen",
                                          user_id: other_user.id)

      visit posts_path

      expect(page).to_not have_content(/This post shouldn't be seen/)
    end
  end

  describe 'new' do
    it "has a link from the homepage" do
      visit root_path

      click_link("new_post_from_nav")
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end
  end

  describe 'delete' do
    it 'can be deleted' do
      logout(:user)

      delete_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      login_as(delete_user, :scope => :user)

      post_to_delete = Post.create(date: Date.today, rationale: 'rationale', user_id: delete_user.id)

      visit posts_path

      click_link("delete_post_#{post_to_delete.id}_from_index")
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end
  end

  describe 'creation' do
    before do
      visit new_post_path
    end

    it 'has a new form that can be reached' do
      expect(page.status_code).to eq(200)
    end

    it 'can be created from a new form page' do
      fill_in 'post[date]', with: Date.today
      fill_in 'post[rationale]', with: "Some rationale"
      click_on "Save"

      expect(page).to have_content("Some rationale")
    end

    it 'will have a user associated with it' do
      fill_in 'post[date]', with: Date.today
      fill_in 'post[rationale]', with: "User Association"
      click_on "Save"

      expect(User.last.posts.last.rationale).to eq("User Association")
    end
  end

  describe 'edit' do

    it "can be edited" do
      visit edit_post_path(post)

      fill_in 'post[date]', with: Date.today
      fill_in 'post[rationale]', with: "Edited content"
      click_on "Save"

      expect(page).to have_content("Edited content")
    end

    it "cannot be edited by a non authorized user" do
      logout(:user)
      non_authorized_user = FactoryGirl.create(:non_authorized_user)
      login_as(non_authorized_user, :scope => :user)

      visit edit_post_path(post)

      expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)
    end
  end
end
```

I review the views/post/_form.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for @post, class: "form-horizontal" do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
      <%= js add_gritter(error, title: "Overtime App Notification", sticky: false, image: :notice) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :date, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <%= f.date_field :date, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :rationale, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <%= f.text_area :rationale, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <%= render partial: 'status', locals: {f: f} if current_user.type == 'AdminUser' %>

    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block' %>
<% end %>
```

I can't tell what is going wrong here. If I inspect element, it's there:

[image]

This is my post.rb model file:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: {submitted: 0, approved: 1, rejected: 2}
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :date, :rationale

  scope :posts_by, ->(user) {where(user_id: user.id)}
end
```

The tests were passing yesterday, not sure what happened.

Comment: can you paste your `post.rb` model, please.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain this, but in your `post.rb` you have `scope :posts_by, ->(user) {where(user_id: user.id)}`. Above that you have `belongs_to :user`, then `validates_presence_of :date, :rationale`. Yet in your test you have `login_as(@user, :scope => :user)`. User as an instance variable of `@user`. Remove the `@` and let me know if that works.

Comment: @Daniel, this worked, thank you! Go ahead and write it as an answer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're calling `login_as` with `@user`, but `@user` is never defined, you probably want `login_as(user)`.
2. Always try to retrace your steps, if something was working before, think about what code you introduced between the last time it worked and when it began failing.
3. Checking status codes is generally a bad smell for feature tests, just check for things the user can see.
4. Don't use the `eq` matcher with `current_path` instead use the `have_current_path` matcher provided by `Capybara`.